# Reactive variable declaration in Svelte doesn't update

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I've got the following code (excerpt):

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { MyStore } from "../stores/MyStore";
    $: numberOfSelectedItems = $MyStore.items.length;
    ...
function myFunction() {
    ...
    $MyStore.items.push(selectedItem);
    ...
}
</script>

...
<p>You've selected {numberOfSelectedItems} items.</p>
```

The problem is that the `numberOfSelectedItems` isn't updated when the items array in the store is changed. The behaviour is the same when I directly try to use `$MyStore.items.length` within the paragraph (`<p>...</p>`).

When I do it like shown below it works, but I think I'm making a mistake and there should be a better way:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { MyStore } from "../stores/MyStore";
    let myLength = 0;
    $: numberOfSelectedItems = myLength;
    ...

    function myFunction() {
        ...
        $MyStore.items.push(selectedItem);
        myLength = $MyStore.items.length;
        ...
    }
</script>
...
<p>You've selected {myLength} items.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Svelte, the reactivity of variables and stores is triggered only by assignment. So Svelte does not consider `$MyStore.items.push(selectedItem)` as a change of the store.

The correct way is either

```js
$MyStore.items = [...$MyStore.items, selectedItem];
```

or

```js
$MyStore.items.push(selectedItem);
// trigger the reactivity
$MyStore.items = $MyStore.items;
```

Comment: Or just `$MyStore = $MyStore` (will both produce the same output)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "triggered only by assignment"!